# Highlightning Keywords in Solr

Tags: solr, highlight

After tweaking around a lot, I finally decided to post this query of mine. Kindly help!!!

So the query is I want to highlight the search keywords in the result section of the Ajax-Solr.
I tried editing the reuters.js ,reuters.theme.js and Resultwidget.js files, but to no luck.I read that I need to add those keywords in  tag , but how to add them is not explained anywhere.

I followed this http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters but couldnt understand it as it does not explains how to implement it.

Kindly help me.
Thanks